# What do you call a protostar with more than 10 solar masses?

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, protostar

PMS Stars with less than 3 solar masses are T Tauri stars, and PMS stars between 3 and 10 solar masses are herbig ae/be stars, so what do you call a star with  more than 10 solar masses? Is there another term for it, or is it unanswered.

Comment: I propose "real big gas ball".

Comment: Anything you want to .  It won't mind.